# Best practice index for date and time?

Tags: mysql, indexing

For **date and time indexing purposes**, of the following, which is the best/best practice/fastest?

1. keep a type `date` and another for `time` and have index on type `date` column
2. keep a single `datetime` column and simply put an index on type `datetime` column
3. have two, a `datetime` column and a `date` column, but put a single index on `date`
4. keep a type `date` and another for `time` and have index on both , first date and then time
5. any other approach?

I want to query a table for detecting changes, so I need both date and time.

UPDATE : I thought datetime indexing would take much more space than a date, so it would effect systems performance, is it true?

Comment: Possibly true about the datetime indexing. But you need the time anyway and in combination with the date you cause more overhead if you have both and an index across them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to save the date and the time that is on the same day as the date:

2. A datetime column can be used by date queries as well as time based queries. I can't see a reason why you would want another field.

Comment: I saw that - I commented on your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a unix timestamp in a int field, easiest to add, subtract and compare. You can convert to different formats for display.